# Broken images in calendar feed in Plone CMS

Tags: python, plone

We periodically have broken images in the calendar feed on the main home page, http://cnr.foo.edu. The problem appears to be that our script that pulls the feed into the home page is prepending http://events.foo.edu onto all image URLs, which creates a failure when the image in question is hosted on a remote server rather than the calendar network server. How can I tweak the script so that it will not add the root calendar URL if an image URL already contains http?

Here is a snippet of the python script that I need to modify:

```
<div class="campus-calendar-event">
        <div class="image-left" style="width: 40px;" tal:condition="python: event['Image']">
            <a tal:attributes="href python:'http://events.foo.edu/index.php/calendar/sn/coe.html?event_ID=%s' % event['ID'];
               title python: event['Title']">
               <img tal:condition="python: event['Image']"
                 tal:attributes="src python: 'http://events.foo.edu%s' % event['Image']['URL'];
                                 alt python: event['Title'];
                                 width string:40px " /></a>
        </div>
```

How can i add an "if" statement to omit the "http://events.foo.edu" part, if 'URL' already contains a "http" (the link to remote server)? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a stopgap, this might work (untested -- I don't have an installation at home):

```
<img tal:define="url python: event['Image'] and event['Image']['URL'];"
     tal:condition="python: event['Image']"
     tal:attributes="src python: url if url.startswith('http') else 'http://events.foo.edu%s' % (url,);
                     alt python: event['Title'];
                     width string:40px " /></a>
```

(Note that your code doesn't handle `event['Image']` not having an entry `URL`, neither does mine.)

There's probably a more elegant solution to be had using `urlsplit`/`urljoin`, though, which would dissect your url into protocol, server, path, query, fragment, and you could reassemble it from there.

In detail, we define a variable `url` to save ourselves a bit of typing -- we first have to check again that `event['Image']` is present. The whole tag is protected by a `tal:condition` that does this, but the order of execution is always `define`, `condition`, `repeat`, `content`/`replace`, `attributes`, `omit`; this is so you can define a variable and use it in the condition clause. We could name it `URL`, but I don't usually name my variables in all-caps. `x and y` in python yields the value of `x` if it is falsy and the value of `y` if it is truthy, so in the usual case, we'll get the url-ish string from your object.

The new attributes clause might be confusing because it's underparenthized: in more detail, it's

```
url if url.startswith('http') else ('http://events.foo.edu%s' % (url,));
```

so it's the usual string formatting. Seeing how the `%s` is at the end, we coud probably say `'http://events.foo.edu'+url`, but "don't concatenate constants and user data together" triggers my "is this a possible command injection vulnerability" reflex.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will modify the original code and will test it. Is ['URL'] and url in your code case-sensitive? What does the (url,) in the end of the tal:attributes statement mean? In <img tal:define we have ['URL']. I am very new to tal. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Gregg: I've added a few more notes.

Comment: Thank you, Ulrich! What does a comma in (url,) in the tal:attributes statement mean? I thought that there should be two conditions: the first tal:condition should check: if there is no 'http' in the event['Image']['URL'] , then the tal:attributes statement that already exists is true. Then the second tal:condition should check, if there is a 'http' in the event['Image']['URL'], then we just need to omit the part 'http://events.foo.edu%s' %" in the tal:attributes statement related to this condition. As I understand, your new attributes clause does the job, correct? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Gregg: `%` substitution takes a list or tuple, so you can do things like `"%s, %s' % ('Hello', 'Gregg'). I don't even  remember if there's a special case for a single element (apparently there is, or your code wouldn't have worked), I always pass a tuple, even if it is a one-element one.

Comment: @Gregg: the `tal:condition` only checks if any kind of link should be created; you are correct that the `attributes` clause puts the extra link prefix or not.